# Чи має термін “діагностика” синоніми українського походження?

Tags: from-english, терміни, синоніми

Досить часто в різних галузях та сферах зустрічається термін "даігностика". Зацікавило походження даного слова та його відповідники в українській мові.

Вікіпедіє [надає](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0) наступне пояснення цьому терміну:

> **Діагно́стика** (з грец. diagnosis = dia+gnosis = «роз+пізнання») (*англ. diagnostics; нім. Diagnostik; фр. le diagnostic*) — галузь знань, що вивчає теорію і методи організації процесів постановки діагнозу, а також принципи побудови засобів діагностування.
>   Наприклад:
>   **Діагностування мінералів** — галузь знань, що вивчає теорію і методи організації процесів визначення мінералів, а також принципи побудови засобів діагностування.
>   **Технічна діагностика** — галузь науково-технічних знань, сутність якої складають теорія, методи і засоби постановки діагнозу про стан технічних об'єктів.
>   **Технічне діагностування** — визначення технічного стану об'єкта з означеною (заданою) точністю.
>   **Медична діагностика** — галузь науково-медичних знань, сутність якої складають теорія, методи і засоби постановки діагнозу про стан пацієнта.
>   **Діагностування (в медицині)** — процес визначення фізичного стану пацієнта і його оцінки, вираженої у прийнятій медичній термінології, що ґрунтується на всебічному систематичному дослідженні організму пацієнта.
>   **Психодіагностика** — галузь психології, яка розробляє теорію, принципи та інструменти оцінки і вимірювання індивідуально-психологічних особливостей особистості.
>   **Педагогічна діагностика** — це підрозділ педагогіки, що вивчає принципи і методи розпізнавання та встановлення ознак, що характеризують нормальний або з відхилом від норм перебіг педагогічного процесу. Іноді розглядається як один з різновидів психологічної діагностики.

На Словотворі до "діагностики" не добрались, пошук "діагностики" на [Вікісловнику](https://uk.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&title=%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0:%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA&profile=default&fulltext=1&searchToken=9ywvt37dc00fjgulq7l5r5is0) та в [Словнику синонімів на офіційному сайті Української мови](https://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0&t=0), результатів не дав. Словник українських синонімів на "Синоніми.укр" теж не став у [нагоді](https://xn--h1aaldafs6o.xn--j1amh/%D0%94/%D0%B4%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0).

[Практичний словник синонімів української мови](http://chtyvo.org.ua/authors/Karavanskyy_Sviatoslav/Praktychnyi_slovnyk_synonimiv_ukrainskoi_movy_5-te_vyd_2014/). 5-те вид., опрацьоване і доповн. Львів, Караванського Святослава, слово "діагностика" не містить.

СУМ-20 [надає](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=22477&page=767) наступний матеріал:

> **ДІАГНО́СТИКА**, и, ж. Галузь знань, що вивчає теорію і методи організації процесів встановлення діагнозу, а також принципи побудови засобів діагностування. Медична діагностика як науковий предмет включає три основні розділи: семіотику (симптоми хвороб та їх діагностичне значення), діагностичну техніку, методологічні основи, які визначають теорію і методи діагнозу (з наук. літ.); Психологічна діагностика розробляє теорію, принципи та інструменти оцінки й вимірювання індивідуально-психологічних особливостей особистості (з наук.-попул. літ.); Метою технічної діагностики є підвищення надійності та ресурсу технічних систем (із журн.).

Отже, чи має термін “діагностика” синоніми українського походження?

Answer (score 2):

В [дослідженні](http://periodicals.karazin.ua/philology/article/view/10144/9671), присвяченому спробам і доцільності впровадження питомих українських слів замість запозичених термінів, є така думка:

> Серед позитивних визначають такі риси пуризму, як збереження
>   самобутності національної мови, стабільність літературних норм,
>   пропагування виражальних засобів рідної мови, використання її
>   лексико-семантичних, фразеологічних, граматичних можливостей для
>   передання нових понять; збагачення літературної мови за рахунок
>   народної. Негативним у пуризмі є його надмірне прагнення очистити мову
>   від усіх запозичень, незважаючи на їх усталеність; догматичне
>   проголошення незмінності літературних норм; нерозуміння поступального
>   розвитку мови; запровадження штучних норм, які відмежовують
>   літературну мову від мовної практики; антиісторизм в оцінці розвитку
>   мови та ретроспективність; неприйняття будь-яких новотворів та
>   однобічне сприйняття мовного контакту
>   Зважаючи на глобалізацію сучасного суспільства й науки, на захист
>   запозичень у науково-технічній термінології стають учені конкретних
>   галузей та мовознавці. Але ж до запозичень можна вдаватися, якщо: 1)
>   їх не вдається замінити засобами української мови; 2) вони стійко
>   ввійшли до складу української лексики; 3) відповідне запозичення має
>   точніше значення, ніж українській термін. Не слід надмірно
>   заперечувати запозичення, оскільки це, на думку О. Іващишина, може
>   призвести до ізоляції національної науки та побудувати перешкоди для
>   обміну досвідом між дослідниками, що спілкуються різними мовами.

Існує слово діагностика за значенням "Галузь знань, що вивчає теорію і методи організації процесів встановлення діагнозу, а також принципи побудови засобів діагностування". Воно усталене, широковживане і має походження з давньогрецької мови (що важливо). В українській мові повного відповідника немає, бо бо ширше оцінку, і тести, і випробування. То чи не залишити його як є?

Answer (score 1):

І справді більшість онлайн перекладачів дають варіант "діагностика" при перекладів слова "diagnostics" чи "диагностика". Але якщо перевірити усі синоніми цього слова не лише в українській мові, але й інших, наприклад [російській](https://sinonim.org/s/%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0), то ми побачимо, що замість слова "діагностика" можна вживати такі слова як: "випробовування", ще кращий варіант "перевірка", або такі запозичені слова як "тест" чи "аналіз". А згідно до словника Мультитран, то можливі ще такі варіанти як "оцінка", "пошук неполадок" чи "виявлення помилок" (якщо ми говоримо про якусь техніку чи програмне забезпечення"), "експертиза", "профілактичний ремонт" (знову ж таки, коли говоримо про якусь техніку).

І все ж, на мою думку, коли ми говоримо про медицину, то краще вживати слово "діагностика", а не замінювати його.